# Setting SAML attributes from SOAP message

Tags: soap, cxf, saml

I am new to SAML. I want to set SAML 2.0 attribute and attribute values from SOAP message. How should I do that? I am using Apache-cxf for SOAP request and response. Please guide me on getting SOAP message and setting the SAML attribute values based on query from SOAP message. I'm also not sure how to dynamically set SAML attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

There are many variants on including SAML attributes in SOAP calls.

First of all you can't include SAML attributes on their own, they will need to be included in an [SAML assertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0). Exact requirements on what should be the content of the assertion, what signatures need to be used, what attributes should be included should be provided by the service you try to call and you should sort that part out first.

With SAML assertion content ready, you'll need to define how to include it in the SOAP calls. Again, there are different possibilities, you could serialize the assertion as an HTTP header when making the call, you could add it as a SOAP header, you could also follow standard way defined in Web Service Security standard, [see SAML profile](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-SAMLTokenProfile.pdf). Again, the exact place on where to add the SAML assertion should be provided by the service you try to call (e.g. inside in its WS-Policy document included in the WSDL).

Once you're done with the pre-requisites, you can for example follow tutorial for including of SAML assertions using CXF [available here](http://coheigea.blogspot.fi/2011/04/saml-support-in-cxf-240.html).